# EULA questions about Microsoft Windows and Samsung

Tags: eula

I have questions about two EULAs, Samsung and Microsoft, and a BONUS one too if you know it off-hand.

Samsung I got no clear answer from from them, and am now asking the dev forum, but I won't be getting anything from there I bet.

So, let's say I use the "pm uninstall -k --user 0" command to uninstall Samsung Bixby, or Messages, or Emergency Mode, or the Edge panels, or S Finder, or any other apk pre-installed by Samsung. Does this violate the EULA, which I think is at this link https://www.samsung.com/sg/Legal/SamsungLegal-EULA/

Second, for Microsoft, whose support chat page hanged twice and I'm going to get the Samsung run-around from them because this is a legal dept question the tech support people don't know about it.

I'd reckon such removals are fine.

According to the Windows EULA, relevant part 2C https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm

Would anything at all that could be done solely with regedit, cmd, powershell, and the permissions editor in File Explorer--all of which are provided by Microsoft--or some combination thereof, be acceptable under the EULA? I'd guess that these would not be violations of the EULA, since whatever is done with those, it is within the limitations of the software. I can't see what else it would violate other than 2C.

Moreover, removals of applications like the Microsoft Store, Edge, etc., all of which can be done with the above-mentioned tools, if done with a third-party application, would that infringe upon the EULA? I wouldn't think so.

Finally, if anybody knows off-hand whether removing cell-carrier applications or bloatware using the above-mentioned ADB method is a violation of the carrier EULAs, I'd be most appreciative.

I don't have any lawyers breathing down my necks or anything. This is solely for my own aedification.

I'd contact the legal depts directly, but it'd be slow and they deal with actual lawsuits and subpoenas and the like and I'd rather not attach my name to some rather simple question with at most a minor practical effect.

Yours Truly,

Stinkoman

Comment: We can’t give you legal advice. Telling you what a contract means is legal advice.

Comment: I was under the impression you could answer anything subject to that disclaimer that this was in no way a substitute for an actual legal consult. So not even this boilerplate EULA stuff can be commented on? Moreover, and no offense meant, but the other questions seem to be full of advice that can potentially be acted upon about legal matters. Surely not everything answered on this stackexchange is hypothetical?

Comment: @Stinkoman20X6: While it is true that many questions have lots of potential legal advice, and many questioners are looking for at least initial legal advice, the answers tend to be theoretical in nature, using the individual question as an example (though I know I myself have been guilty of answers that toe and possibly go over that line).That said, I think the EULA answers your question in plain and non-confusing language, if you read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided Samsung EULA, Section 3 "Limitations on End User Rights":

> You shall not ... modify, or disable any features of, the Software.

Which sounds like the EULA prohibits your proposed course of action. Now, that section, like lots of section in this EULA and many other EULAs have, many caveats about sections not applying if in contravention of laws (which is usually true even if not explicitly stated), but whether or not that is true in your proposal is getting into the realm of specific legal advice, for which I would advise you to retain a lawyer.